# How to line break in Facebook C# SDK Post?

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been messing with the Facebook C# SDK using WP7 and managed to post to my wall. My question is how do I do line breaks in the post description?

\n\r
\r
\n
do not seem to work.

my code Note:_fb = FacebookClient

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["name"] = "";
args["caption"] = "Testing WP7 app";
args["description"] = "Line1\rLine2\rLine3";
args["picture"] = "";
args["message"] = "Testing";
args["actions"] = "";

_fb.PostCompleted += new EventHandler<Facebook.FacebookApiEventArgs>_fb_PostCompleted);
_fb.PostAsync("me/feed", args);
```

Edit:
Looks like center does the trick like so.

```
args["description"] = "Line1<center></center>Line2<center></center>Line3";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `<br />` or `<p />` work?

Comment: If I understand what your saying I tried both in one go like so  Line1<br />Line2<p />Line3   and neither worked. Have I wrote that right?